# Outlook VBA: Application_ItemSend save send mailitem

Tags: vba, outlook

I would like to save the sent mailitem. When doing this with the Application_ItemSend event, invoking there the function saveAs, the mailitem is saved in the state before being sent (still in draft mode), but I need to save the mailitem in the state of sent mode.

Thanks for your feedback

Markus

Comment: Monitor the sent items folder and process any new arrivals

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your suggestion. Now, when monitoring in the outlook session the sent items folder, I obtain the correct mail item.

Comment: Things are more complicated rather than monitoring the Sent Items folder.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to save the item to a specific Outlook folder you can set the [MailItem.SaveSentMessageFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.savesentmessagefolder) property which returns or sets a `Folder` object that represents the folder in which a copy of the email message will be saved after being sent. So, in the `ItemSend` event handler you just set the property to the required folder and the sent item will be placed to that folder automatically (instead of `Sent Items` folder).

But if you need to save the sent item to a folder on the disk the implementation is a bit harder. In the `ItemSend` event handler you need to check out the [SaveSentMessageFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.savesentmessagefolder) property value. If it is not set then the message will be put to the `Sent Items` folder. Of course, if the [DeleteAfterSubmit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.deleteaftersubmit) property is not set up, it returns or sets a boolean value that is `true` if a copy of the mail message is not saved upon being sent, and `false` if a copy is saved in `Sent Items` folder. In the target folder where the sent item can be placed you need to set up the `ItemAdd` event handler. In the event handler you can get the item instance (passed as a parameter) and save it on the disk.